# Column casting syntax

Tags: pyspark

I have spaces in the columns coming into and out of this pyspark command:

```
results2 = results.select( cast("`HCAHPS Base Score`" as int), `HCAHPS Base Score`, cast("HCAHPS Consistency Score" as int) `HCAHPS Consistency Score` )
```

and I'm getting a SyntaxError at the beginning of the first as int (in front of as).

Answer (score 0):

Casting in pyspark is done like,

```
results2 = results.select( results['HCAHPS Base Score'].cast(IntergerType()),results['HCAHPS Consistency Score'].cast(IntegerType()))
```